# Setting Stockfish at 2900 strength for a match against top 1-5 GMs

Tags: engines, human-versus-machine, match

Obviously stockfish 15 is well above the capabilities of any human to even draw a game, Hikaru Nakamura needed a handicap of 2 pawns from the side of Komodo only to lose 1.5-0.5 in a mini match against Komodo(he lost with the black pieces and drew with white).I was wondering if we could set up Stockfish at a playing strength of 2900 , would that be interesting for a human-engine match without odds?Have there been proposed such kind of matches?

Answer (score 1):

No, playing with engines in lower level it is not so interesting. Usually they play better than the level you have chosen and suddenly they blunder. Nothing interesting and nothing human.

So if Carlsen plays a match against Stockfish 2900, he will play against Stockfish 3300 or 3500 for the first 15 or 20 moves (nothing interesting so far) and suddenly while Stockfish knight is ready to fork the rook and king of Carlsen (anyone at 1000+ elo can see it)... Stockfish blunders and plays a so wacky, null and void and senseless move (nothing human finally). But even if the engine plays continuously at 2900 level without blunders, again it would not be interesting. It would be like a match between a 8-year-old boy who is at 1700 elo and it is expected to reach 2800 after 10 years, playing against a crazy man 70 years old who was 2400 when he was young, but after 15 years in a psychiatric institution, his level got to 1800.

So at the moment, it would be more interesting if the world champion plays against the best Stockfish without 2 or 3 pawns.

Comment: "So at the moment, it would be more interesting if the world champion plays against the best Stockfish without 2 or 3 pawns.".Funnily Hikaru played against Komodo , which is much inferior to Stockfish a 2 game mini match with 2 pawn odds and Komodo won the match 1.5-0.5.And Hikaru was #3 in the world at that moment